# Why CNN model training for an Image classification task with Keras and Python giving erros

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, image-processing, keras

I am new to Image processing and using keras and tensorflow for multi-image classification. The code I am working with is given below:

```
   import tensorflow as tf
   from tensorflow.keras import datasets, layers, models
   import pandas as pd
   import numpy as np
```

The dataset is already divided into train and test sets. The train and test sets are arrays of images and the labels are taken from csv file.

```
   X_train = np.load('X_train_images.npy')
   X_test =  np.load('X_test_images.npy')
   Y_train = pd.read_csv('Y_train_Labels.csv',encoding='latin-1')
   Y_test =  pd.read_csv('Y_test_Labels.csv',encoding='latin-1')
 
   Y_train = Y_train['label'].to_numpy()
   Y_test = Y_test['label'].to_numpy()
   
   print(X_train.shape)
   print(X_test.shape)
   print(Y_train.shape)
   print(Y_test.shape)
```

So the shape of the datasets are:

```
  (4000, 4, 4, 512)
  (1000, 4, 4, 512)
  (4000,)
  (1000,)
```

So defining the model:

```
  batch_size=32
  epochs=10

  model=tf.keras.Sequential() 
  model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32,kernel_size=(3,3),activation='relu',input_shape=(4,4,512)))
  model.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2))) 
  #I'm adding two Dropout layers to prevent overfitting 
  model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.25)) 
  model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten()) 
  model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1024,activation='relu')) 
  model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5)) 
  model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(10,activation='softmax'))
```

Compiling the model and then training it:

```
   model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',     
                  optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001,decay=1e-6), metrics=['accuracy']) 

   model.fit(X_train/255.0, tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(Y_train), 
             batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=False, epochs=epochs, 
             validation_data=(X_test/255.0, tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(Y_test)) 
            )
```

Finally the prediction scores:

```
   predictions=model.predict(x_test) 
   scores = model.evaluate(x_test / 255.0, tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(y_test)
                          )
```

While training the model, i am getting an input shape error at:

```
    validation_data=(X_test/255.0, tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(Y_test))
```

The error is:

```
    ValueError: Shapes (32, 9) and (32, 10) are incompatible
```

I don't understand why i am getting this error as i know that it is because of the shape of the classes ?

Thanks

Comment: Looks like shape mismatch: your layer signature `input_shape=(512,4,4)` , you are trying to feed   `(batch, 4, 4, 512)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is data and model input shape mismatch: your input is `input_shape=(512,4,4)` while train data have shape `batch, 4, 4, 512` . If model's input planned to be of that shape - change your data with `numpy.transpose()` to match model's input. Otherwise change your model input.

The same issue with output but caused by different problem: model generates output as dense list while train data is coded by class numbers. Solution convert input data to categorical:

```
from tf.keras.utils import to_categorical
# define example
data = [1, 3, 2, 0, 3, 2, 2, 1, 0, 1]
data = array(data)
print(data)
# one hot encode
encoded = to_categorical(data)
```

Check [details](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/to_categorical) and [tutorial](https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-one-hot-encode-sequence-data-in-python/)

Comment: i update the shape but the new error is:ValueError: Shapes (32, 1) and (32, 10) are incompatible

Comment: Your model generates array of 10 values, with all zero but one "1" which indicates predicted class. Your train data provides 1 number - class index. Convert them to categorical: to_categorical(data)

Comment: Thank you but when i correct one error comes another. Now its index error when converting to categories with  tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(Y_train). IndexError: index -9223372036854775808 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 8

Comment: Check if you read values from your data file correctly. They should be in range [0...9] if you have 10 classes in dataset. Pay attention to your  "encoding" param.

Comment: Data should be free of NaN. If you have data that does not correspond to any needed class, do not include it into your dataset. Or make numbered class "others" and put all your NaN there. But it can cause problems with training: you can get low accuracy and no convergence.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225589/discussion-between-alex-k-and-codedb).